# How to rspec threaded code?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, rspec

Starting using rspec I have difficulties trying to test threaded code.
Here is a simplicfication of a code founded, and I made it cause i need a Queue with Timeout capabilities

```
require "thread"

class TimeoutQueue
   def initialize
      @lock = Mutex.new
      @items = []
      @new_item = ConditionVariable.new
   end

   def push(obj)
      @lock.synchronize do
         @items.push(obj)
         @new_item.signal
      end
   end

   def pop(timeout = :never)
      timeout += Time.now unless timeout == :never
      @lock.synchronize do
         loop do
            time_left = timeout == :never ? nil : timeout - Time.now
            if @items.empty? and time_left.to_f >= 0
               @new_item.wait(@lock, time_left)
            end
            return @items.shift unless @items.empty?
            next if timeout == :never or timeout > Time.now
            return nil
         end
      end
   end

   alias_method :<<, :push
end
```

But I can't find a way to test it using rspec. Is there any effective documentation on testing threaded code? Any gem that can helps me?
I'm a bit blocked, thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When unit-testing we don't want any non-deterministic behavior to affect our tests, so when testing threading we *should not* run anything in parallel.

Instead, we should isolate our code, and *simulate* the cases we want to test, by stubbing `@lock`, `@new_item`, and perhaps even `Time.now` (to be more readable I've taken the liberty to imagine you also have `attr_reader :lock, :new_item`):

```
it 'should signal after push' do
  allow(subject.lock).to receive(:synchronize).and_yield

  expect(subject.new_item).to receive(:signal)

  subject.push('object')

  expect(subject.items).to include('object')
end

it 'should time out if taken to long to enter synchronize loop' do
  @now = Time.now
  allow(Time).to receive(:now).and_return(@now, @now + 10.seconds)
  allow(subject.items).to receive(:empty?).and_return true
  allow(subject.lock).to receive(:synchronize).and_yield

  expect(subject.new_item).to_not receive(:wait)

  expect(subject.pop(5.seconds)).to be_nil
end
```

etc...

Comment: ok thanks again ;) So if I get it correctly I will not test filling the queue on one thread and receiving a value on another. Will try to keep that in mind, but somehow it sucks as i'm developping an interface to a command line that can reads input... it's gonna be a tough thing to test :/

Comment: You should _simulate_ all use cases. Simulate a case where `@items` is empty, expect `wait` to be called, put an item inside `@items`, and see that it is returned...

Comment: ok so what i do is i deconstruct each process for every use case and test that on it's own, by 'simulating the other process' but i do not test two process running in parrallel. Hopefully I did get it ;) Thnaks a lot for your explanations

Comment: That's just silly to say that you should never test multi-threaded code in parallel. Obviously its good to test your program's logic in a primarily single-threaded way since that is more clear and easy to reason about. However, if you're using threads, say hello to non-determinism! You *can* and should test non-deterministic code, though there are caveats. 

If you don't have any integration tests that run with multiple threads you're not testing your real program.

Comment: @AndrewCholakian - I did not say "never test multi-threaded code" - that is silly indeed. I said you should not _unit test_ in a non deterministic way! Unit testing is all about confidence in your code. If your unit test _sometimes_ fail - when it succeeds you know nothing - it may fail the next time... Instead you should _simulate_ the non-deterministic behavior in a deterministic fashion (so that it will _always_ fail) - that way you know you haven't broken your code. Of course, integration/system/stress testing et al. should be run in real conditions, as close to prod as possible.

Comment: @UriAgassi your post still says "when testing threading we should not run anything in parallel." There are deterministic things that can run in parallel.

Comment: @UriAgassi also, you sometimes have to test non-deterministic things. For instance, any test that involves I/O or time is technically non-deterministic. Any of those things can fail at any time! Maybe your app doesn't run after the year 2018, who knows. Or, perhaps you're worried about races. Often times seriously parallel code will have stress tests where the same tight loops are run millions or billions of times looking for races. This is totally legitimate, there aren't other ways of finding those errors outside of just staring at code.

Comment: @AndrewCholakian, there are deterministic things you can run in parallel, but running your tests in parallel _might_ cause failures due to running two unrelated tests at the same time, reducing your confidence in your failures (i.e. a test fails when there is no bug to fix).

Comment: @AndrewCholakian - In regard to testing non-deterministic things, like I/O and time - you have to _make_ them deterministic by stubbing and spoofing them - need to test a race condition? simulate it! Want to test what happens in 2018 - make `Time.now` return a date in 2018... Sure, stress-tests have their place, and are very important, but they are not unit-tests, which is the scope of this discussion...